# What is a metaboliser?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

What is a "metaboliser" for a linking form? This term appears in a recent paper on the Hopf link and I cannot find any definition on the net or in any texts.

I am a professional topologist trying to review a paper.

Comment: Try googling with the American spelling "metabolizer".  Combining it with "linking form" I got several plausible-looking hits, starting with http://books.google.com/books?id=EyYWVnK5z44C&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=metabolizer+%22linking+form%22&source=bl&ots=wW7VMPZ6Qz&sig=SQf4c544FC96JTsa3qhS4hz7rnk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5vKdU5XcKuaisQSc04EI&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=metabolizer%20%22linking%20form%22&f=false

Comment: I would just write in the referee's report that that term needs to be defined. Definitions may reasonably be omitted only if the author can reasonably expect them to be known to readers of the paper.

Comment: I think the context for Stefan Kohl's comment above was lost with the previous edit. The original title of the question was "professional topologist trying to review a paper", implying that this was meant for an article currently under review.

Comment: @ricardo: I added that sentence back to the body.

Answer (score 3):

There is a definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form#Split_quadratic_space).

The *metabolizer* of a bilinear form $\beta(x,y)$ on a vector space $V$ is a subspace $W$ that equals its [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) $W^{\perp}$. The bilinear form itself is then called *metabolic*.

The metabolizer of a metabolic bilinear form is sometimes referred to as its *lagrangian*, see paragraph 1.C on page 17 of [The Algebraic and Geometric Theory of Quadratic Forms](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~karpenko/publ/Kniga.pdf).

For applications of this concept in the context of knot theory (which I presume is the relevant context in your case), see
[Some examples related to knot sliceness](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404906001897), section 2.1, and
[Metabolic and hyperbolic forms from knot theory](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/levineform.pdf), section 2.